# jQuery UI datepicker and dialog box undefined first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Using jQuery UI datepicker and dialog box to work with returned data from a rest call.

The first click of a date with an event spawns the dialog box however the contents state undefined. Console logging this out shows the same result.

The second click of the same event will spawn the modal with actual content.

If you click previous or next to navigate through the months, that eliminates any event contents returning undefined.

Is there something I'm missing for initializing my calendar? I looked at the documentation and was hoping there was an onLoad instead of onSelect. The first select always shows undefined and no data is shown, though the data is clearly loaded.

```
 $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: [1, 1],
    dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
    changeYear: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    navigationAsDateFromat: false,
    dayNamesMin: ["S", "M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S"],
    defaultDate: new Date(),
    beforeShowDay: highlightDays,
    onSelect: function(date) {
        var events = $('<div class=\"event\">');
        var strYear;
        var strMonth;
        var strDay;
        for (var i = 0; i < dat.length; i++) {
            if (dates[i] === date) {

                // SHOW EVENT DETAILS
                events.append("<div class=\"cal\"><div><div>" + dat[i].Time+ "</div> \
                                   <div>" + dat[i].content "</div>");

                $("#title").html(events);
            }
        }

        $("#dialog").dialog({
            title: "Special Event",
            draggable: true,
            closeOnEscape: true,
            closeText: "CLOSE"
        });

        // END SHOW EVENTS        
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't know if this is right, but I would first try stepping through it and seeing if you get the same result. If you don't, then it probably means that in runtime you're setting up the dialog box before your for loop is finished running. (An asynchronous thing.) If so, then you can try putting a variable in your for loop and set it on the last iteration of the loop, and then check the variable before running your dialog box.

Comment: That helped, now when you click any date on the datepicker the datepicker resizes somewhat then if you click the date again the dialog box appears. Your suggestion with the flag was helpful.

Comment: Good to know, thanks. That suggests that the problem has to do with the for loop and the dialog method running asynchronously. So, you might want to experiment with `setTimeout` instead of the flag, too, to give your for loop a chance to complete before the dialog method gets called.

Comment: Also, it's probably a good idea to create a runnable example here, so people can experiment with ideas to help you. You've seen those "run code snippet" buttons on other posts. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) the doc on how to do that.

Comment: I do not have the button to launch the stack snippet editor, perhaps not enough posts yet? I went back to my initial post but the spot where it is listed is just a white box. Possibly due to a network firewall perhaps.

Comment: For the time being: https://jsfiddle.net/rhyn5w1o/

The json data is just static but you can see what is going on. The flag seemed to work best but requires a second click, the setTimeout did not have any effect oddly enough. I'll keep at it, and thanks again for the tips!

Comment: Ok I sorted it out with your suggestions @BobRodes
I wrapped the datepicker eventhandler with setTimeout and that did the trick.

Not sure why it was needed since all this was done in the callback which has all the data passed back to it. Nonetheless, thank you!

Comment: Sure enough. You might also try initializing your dialog box first, with autoOpen set to false, before initializing your datepicker, and then calling its open method in the datepicker's onSelect event. Might be cleaner than setTimeout.